# How to increase the inputs of each layer in the neural network by a specific scale?

Tags: keras

How to increase the inputs of each layer in the neural network by a specific scale?

I am working on a neural network with Keras and TensorFlow.

I'd like to implement some features in the neural network.  During the training, I want to remove a specific range of input for each layer. For example

Let's say the input of the layer one is a range of [-2 2]. I'd like to make sure no input at [0 0.5]. So I'd like to add 0.5 to all the inputs whose value is at [0 0.5].

How could I do that? during the training process.

Thank you very much

Comment: just curious, why would you like to modify values of layers?

Comment: It is a little hard to explain. I am working on a software-hardware codesign. Something I can not do in hardware part since I can not change the physics. I think maybe I can do something in the software part, then to make my life easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try Lambda functions.  An example implementation below.  I hope this helps.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

from tensorflow.keras import layers
import numpy as np

def myClippingFunction(x):
    y = tf.math.logical_and(tf.math.greater_equal(x, [[0]]), tf.math.less_equal(x, [[0.5]]) )
    z = tf.where(y,x+0.5,x)
    return z

#create simple model
inputA = layers.Input((1,)) 
x = layers.Lambda(myClippingFunction)(inputA)
myModel = keras.Model(inputs=inputA, outputs=x)


x_data = np.array([[-0.2],[0.6]])
myModel.predict(x_data)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It is helpful. But, I am thinking to make this function as an extra layer in Keras. and it popup an error:ValueError: Tried to convert 'x' to a tensor and failed. Error: None values not supported.

Comment: class mylayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        super(mylayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel',
                                      shape=(input_shape[1], self.output_dim),
                                      initializer='uniform',
                                      trainable=True)
        super(my, self).build(input_shape)  
    def call(self, x):

Comment: Sorry for my silly problems, I am not quite familiar with Keras and TensorFlow

Comment: Do I do something on Callback ?